# Need help writing string to HEX in C#

Tags: c#, hex

I am trying to write this into a byte array. I am not sure how to handle the text part.

Example :
Setting an alphanumeric variable named OF with value TEST:

[0x02][0x00][0x35][0x37][0xFF][0x00]OF=TEST[0x00][0x03]

I know how to write the given hex in the above example, however, when I get to the OF=TEST, I need to know how to fit that into the byte array.

```
byte[] byteData = {0x02, 0x00, 0x35, 0x37, 0xFF, What do I do here?, 0x00, 0x03};
```

Comment: How *should* it be written?

Comment: Anyway, using [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) may make this task easier (write prefix, write "TEST" according to rules, write suffix, use `ms.ToArray()`). Alternatively, looking at `IEnumerable.Concat` could help.

Comment: Determine the encoding for the binary data to get a byte[] from the text. E.g if its ASCII use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(...) to get a byte[] from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do you:

```
byte[] octets ;
Encoding someEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false) ;

using( MemoryStream aMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(8192) ) // let's start with 8k
using ( BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter( aMemoryStream , someEncoding ) ) // wrap that puppy in a binary writer
{
  byte[] prefix = { 0x02 , 0x00 , 0x35 , 0x37 , 0xFF , } ;
  byte[] suffix = { 0x00 , 0x03 , } ;

  writer.Write( prefix ) ;
  writer.Write( "OF=TEST" );
  writer.Write( suffix ) ;

  octets = aMemoryStream.ToArray() ;

}

foreach ( byte octet in octets )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "0x{0:X2}" , octet ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] preByteData = {0x02, 0x00, 0x35, 0x37, 0xFF};
byte[] postByteData = {0x00, 0x03};
//using System.Linq;
byte[] byteData = preByteData.Concat(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OF=TEST").Concat(postByteData)).ToArray();
```